# What am I missing to replace everything I want?

Tags: powershell, text, replace, parameters

I need 2 .txt files as parameters. The database.txt looks like this (in this format: name,address,date):
Michael,random street 1,dec.24.
Allen,random street 2,dec.24.
Kevin,random street 3,dec.24.

The text.txt file looks like an e-mail but the important parts are:
Name: /name/
Address: /address/
Date: /date/

I need to display the text.txt for every line of database.txt.
Here is my code:

```
param ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string] $textfile,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string] $datafile )
$text = get-content .\$textfile
$data = get-content .\$datafile
$name = ($data.Split(",")[0])
$address = ($data.Split(",")[1])
$date = ($data.Split(",")[2])

foreach ($line in $textfile){

    $text -replace '/name/',$name
    $text -replace '/address/',$address
    $text -replace '/date/',$date
}
```

The output looks like this:

Name : Michael
Address: /address/
Date: /date/

Name: /name/
Address: random street 1
Date: /date/

Name: /name/
Address: /address/
Date: dec.24.

It should be like this:

Name : Michael
Address: random street 1
Date: dec.24

Name: Allen
Address: random street 2
Date: dec.24

Name: Kevin
Address: random street 3
Date: dec.24.

So my code recognizes only the first line and replaces the data at different times. What can I do to fix the issue? I think my foreach and/or split has something to do with it.
I am really new to powershell so try to keep the solution as simple as possible please. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
$text = @"
Name: /name/
Address: /address/
Date: /date/
"@


$data = @"
Michael,random street 1,dec.24.
Allen,random street 2,dec.24.
Kevin,random street 3,dec.24.
"@

# Split the data into lines
$DataLines = $data -split "`n"

foreach ($line in $dataLines){
    $name = ($line.Split(",")[0])
    $address = ($line.Split(",")[1])
    $date = ($line.Split(",")[2])

    $text -replace '/name/',$name -replace '/address/',$address -replace '/date/',$date
}
```

I put the content directly in the `$text` and `$data` variable for demonstration purposes but this is what your variables would contains when loaded up.

Your initial script had 2 problems.

1. You want to iterate over the data entries (each line of data) and not the text file.

--

```
 $DataLines = $data -split "`n"

foreach ($line in $dataLines){
    $name = ($line.Split(",")[0])
    $address = ($line.Split(",")[1])
    $date = ($line.Split(",")[2])
    #replace here
}
```

2. You want to have 1 output of text and not 3

The replace statement output the full string in your console after the replace operation. 
The original variable is not modified.

```
foreach ($line in $textfile){

    $text -replace '/name/',$name
    $text -replace '/address/',$address
    $text -replace '/date/',$date
}
```

Essentially, you create 3 version of the text.
One with only the name replaced, one with only the address and one with only the date.

You either need to do it all in one line

```
$text -replace '/name/',$name -replace '/address/',$address -replace '/date/',$date
```

or assign the result of each replace operation into a variable, that you reuse on subsequent calls :

```
$MyTextOutput = $text -replace '/name/',$name 
$MyTextOutput = $MyTextOutput -replace '/address/',$address 
$MyTextOutput = $MyTextOutput -replace '/date/',$date
$MyTextOutput
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a csv to me:

```
$text = get-content text.txt
import-csv database.txt -header name,address,date | foreach {
  $text -replace '/name/',$_.name -replace '/address/',$_.address -replace '/date/',$_.date
}
```